# Cosets Multiplication is Well-defined iff the subring is a ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring. $I$ be a subring of $R$.

I can prove the Cosets multiplication $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$ is well defined. i.e if $a+I=a'+I$ and $b+I=b'+I$, then $ab+I=a'b'+I$. iff $I$ is a ideal of $R$.

But I am wondering whether "$(a+I)(b+I):=ab+I$ is equal to $\{(a+i)(b+j):i,j\in H\}$ iff $I$ is an ideal" is true.

I can prove $"\to"$ this direction by noting $ai=(a+0)(0+j) $ and I can prove if $I$ is an ideal, then $\{(a+i)(b+j):i,j\in H\}\subseteq\{ab+i:i\in I\}$ by noting $\forall i,j\in I,ab+I=(a+I)(b+I)=(a+i+I)(b+j+I)=(a+i)(b+j)+I$.

But I am stuck in proving the other side. i.e $ab+i$ can be factorized into $(a+j)(b+k)$ for some $i,k\in I$.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are the $H$s supposed to be $I$s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think that holds.

(Edited for a simpler example)

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $I=(x)$, $a=b=2$. Then $(2+I)(2+I) = 4+I$. But products of the form
$$(2+xp(x))(2+xq(x))$$
with $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ have even linear coefficient, whereas $4+I$ contains the element $4+x$ which is not of that form.

So even though $I$ is an ideal, we have
$$4+I\subsetneq \{ (2+i)(2+j)\mid i,j\in I\}.$$

Even in $\mathbb{Z}$ you run into problems. The set of products $(2+4k)(2+4m)$ gives you elements of the form $4+8r$. Yet $(2+4\mathbb{Z})(2+4\mathbb{Z}) = 4+4\mathbb{Z}$ which contains elements of the form $4+4s$. So while $8$ is clearly in $4+4\mathbb{Z}$, it is not in of the form $(2+4k)(2+4m)$.

Comment: thank you for your help.